# Vicini brand - original or clone?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have seen a racer for sale in BKK, for 2500 Baht, in a scrap yard. It is a bit of a hybrid, but the frame is apparently branded *Vicini*:

[image: Vicini logo on the frame's down tube]

[image: The bicycle in full]

However, the logo doesn't match that which I found on the web. This is the logo, on the bicycle that I found:

[image: Logo on the head tube]

This is the logo that I found [on the web](https://steel-vintage.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/aa42655c8aa426cc3301878712478811/v/i/vicini-campagnolo-classic-steel-bicycle-18.jpg), from [this page](https://steel-vintage.com/vicini-classic-road-bicycle-for-eroica-detail):

[image: Vicini logo from the web]

Does anyone know if this is a good brand, and whether I have found a dusty nugget of treasure, or is it just a no-brand fake clone? I *have* googled for Vincent branded bicycles and not come up with all that much.

---

#### Additional photos and info

FWIW, the rear derailleur mechanism is a Exage 300EX, the gear shifts are Shimano (although the photo is unfocused unfortunately), and the rear brake cable is threaded in-frame inside the top horizontal tube:

[image: In-frame rear brake cable]

The logo can also be seen on the seat tube:

[image: Logo on the seat tube]

[image: Exage 300EX rear derailleur]

[image: Pedal crank arm]

[image: Gear shifters]

[image: Markings on handlebars]

Comment: Note also that the _classic_ "vicini" logomark was all lower-case.

Comment: That is interesting. You wouldn't happen to have a link to an image, would you? I'm wondering whether the logo on the bike is a new modernised version/look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going over the photos again, and then googling "Vicini Special Pro" (as is seen on the seat tube), I found this frame on eBay, going for over 200 Euros:

[image]

Even though the frame isn't exactly the same (the rear brake cable doesn't go inside the frame's top tube), the logos all look the same.

Another link shows a complete bike (with the same frame (brake cable internal)) going for [400 Euros](https://picclick.de/VICINI-Special-Pro-Retro-Stahl-Rennrad-Campagnolo-Veloce-113243729762.html) ([original image](https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/113243729762_/VICINI-Special-Pro-Retro-Stahl-Rennrad-Campagnolo-Veloce.jpg)):

[image: VICINI-Special-Pro-Retro-Stahl-Rennrad-Campagnolo-Veloce (enlarged)]

I think that the whole bike for ~50 Euros (equivalent to 2500 baht) *is* probably worth it...

There's even an interesting Wikipedia page about [Mario Vicini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Vicini) with the following information:

> You can tell his frame and fork sets by the Vicini name stamped into the top end of the seat stay flutes and the V in the top of each side of the fork crown.

As DavidW states in [his comment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/71267/vicini-brand-original-or-clone?noredirect=1#comment162420_71267), the original logo was in lower case, like so ([source](https://steel-vintage.com/vicini-classic-road-bicycle-detail)):

[image: Original Vicini logo]

So, the logo appears to have had a "recent" revamp.